# Laravel: export searched data to the excel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to export searched data to the laravel below is my controller

public function getUsageData(Request $request)
    {

```
    $start_date = $request->get('start_date');
    $end_date = $request->get('end_date');

    $particulars = DB::table('particulars')
        ->join('reqs', 'particulars.particular_id', "=", 'reqs.particular_id')
        ->whereBetween('date_applied', [$start_date, $end_date])
        ->select('particulars.item_name', 'particulars.unit', 'particulars.price', 'reqs.quantity_issued',
            DB::raw('particulars.price*reqs.quantity_issued AS total_cost'))
        ->get();
    if ($particulars->isEmpty()) {


        return "No Records Found...................... ";

    } else {

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('issuer.getUsageReport', ['particulars' => $particulars]);
        return $pdf->stream('getUsageReport.issuer');
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve those data to the excel instead of pdf please help

Answer (score 0):

Replace the two PDF lines in the `else { ... }` statement with:

```
$list = $particulars->toArray();

//This line adds headers if present in your data
array_unshift($list, array_keys($list[0]));

$callback = function() use ($list) {
    $FH = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($list as $row) { 
        fputcsv($FH, $row);
    }
    fclose($FH);
};

return response()->streamDownload($callback,"filename.csv");
```

Depending on the structure of `particulars` you may need to do some manipulation to the data first, e.g. flattening. Comment below if so.

Comment: Am searching data by daterange then the output I want to export it to excel

Comment: Yes, replace `return $pdf->stream('getUsageReport.issuer');` with the code above and let us know if it produces the output you need. If not, we will need to see the data structure.